# Auto populate Lookup Fields related to multiple Objects

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-object, lookup, configuration, admin

I have a custom object called Project, that has related object called Milestone. I then have an object called Log which is related to both a Project and a Milestone.

If you create the log from the realted list of either Project or Milestone then the lookup field will be populated with the respective related record, if however you create a Log on a Milestone you have a huge volume of Project records to sort through to find the correct record.

How can I reduce this lookup 'list' and auto populate the related record?

I have tried lookup filters at field level but this doesn't work with formula fields, and I also looked at Action Buttons but stumbled as we have different types to associate records with.

Am I missing something here, is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm&type=5

> Select a suggested field from the Field text box. You can only select fields on the current record, the lookup object, or the user record. You can also choose related fields that are one relationship away from the lookup object. Salesforce assists you by listing the available fields and relationships when you click the lookup icon or click inside the text box.

you are able to choose fields that are on the current record, the lookup record, and fields from a record that is one relationship away from the lookup record.  While you cannot use the Formula Field itself to filter the record selection in the Lookup field, you should be able to recreate the logic of the Formula within the lookup filter definition.